# Merge 2 images using google app engine and python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I want to merge 2 images and that too at specific location of 1st image.

Example: 
1st image: `x.png` (400 X 400px)
2nd image: `y.png` (at `100,100` co-ordinates)

How can i do this using python in google appengine.?

If you can provide some codes for this ... or any reference to this code... will be appreciated.

Thank you,
Please let me know for more clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done using the very cut down imaging library which emulates some of the functions of PIL.  The function you need is [composite](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html)

```
from google.appengine.api import images

xpng = #Load data from x.png here, or read from BlobProperty
ypng = #Load data from y.png here, or read from BlobProperty

composite = images.composite([(xpng, 0, 0, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT),
    (ypng, 100, 100, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT)], 400, 400)

#composite now holds your new image data, to do what you want with
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `composite` method : [see the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can have look at the composite module in google images api.If it doesntt work . This is also worth giving a try. This is using Image module in python

```
import Image
image1 = Image.open("#imageurl")
iamge2 = Image.open("#imageurl")

image1.paste(image2, (0, 0), image2)
```

Comment: It won't; you can't use PIL directly in App Engine. You're limited to App Engine's imaging API (or, if you can find it, pure python code that manipulates images).